# Whats' wrong?? Why doesn't work this SQLs?

Tags: php, sql, database, oop, insert

Why do these codes not work?

ERROR :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'commodityrecive' (T_STRING),
>   expecting '(' in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trip/control/userchoice_control.php on line
>   275

Code:

```
    //物価に関しての情報を。コンとローる
    static function commodityrecive () {
            //物価の情報を受け取る
        global $commodityget;
        global $sql10;

        $sql5 = sprintf("SELECT commodity FROM contrydata where destname = '%s'",
                    mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['destination'])
                );
        $commodityget = mysqli_query($db,$sql5);


        if(isset($commodityget) && $commodityget != ''){
            if(is_numeric($commodityget)){
                addPrice::commoditycost();

            }else{
                error_echo::commodityrecieve_error1();  
            }
        }else{
            error_echo::commodityrecieve_error2();
        }

    }


    //クオリティ情報のレシーブ@コントローラ
    static function qualityrecive(){

        global $qualityget;
        $qualityget = mysqli_query("SELECT quality FROM serviceuser where destname = $_POST['quality']");
            if(isset($qualityget) && $qualityget != ''){    
                if($qualityget === '高級'){//一般&安い
                    return $qualityhigh;
                    addPrice::qualitycost();

                }else if($qualityget === '一般'){
                    return $qualotynomal;
                    addPrice::qualitycost();

                }else if($qalityget === '安い'){
                    return $qualitylow;
                    addPrice::qualitycost();

                }else{
                    error_echo::qualityreceive_error1();
                }
            }else{
                error_echo::qualityrecieve_error2();
            }




    //人数の情報をレシーブ
    static function ninnzuurecive(){


        $ninnzuuget = mysql_query("SELECT numberofpeople FROM serviceuser where destname = $_POST['ninnzuu']");
        if(isset($ninnzuuget) && $ninnzuuget != ''){
            if(is_numeric($ninnzuuget)){
                continue;
            }else{
                error_echo::ninnzuureceive_error1();
            }

            if(2 <= $ninnzuuget <= 9){  

                return $ninnzuuget;
                addPrice::ninnzuuprice();
                //$以下に注意して
            }else{
                error_echo::ninnzuureceive_error2();
            }

        }else{
            error_echo::ninnzuureceive_error3();
        }
    }       



    //プレゼントの有無とかを受信
    static function surprise(){
        $surpriseget = mysql_query("SELECT surprise FROM serviceuser where destname = $_POST['surprise']");
        if(isset($surpriseget) && $surpriseget != ''){
            //正常
            if($surpriseget === 'あり'){
                addPrice::buyPresent();
                addPrice::surpriseSetting();
            }else　if($surpriseget === 'なし'){
                //つまりはbirthdayクラスには行かないってこと
                finalCalc::plusCalc();

            }else{
                error_echo::surprise_error1();
            }

        }else{
            //異常
            error_echo::surprise_error2();

        }
    }




    static function ogori(){
        //どんくらい奢るのか計算


        $ogoriget = mysql_query("SELECT ogori FROM serviceuser where ogori = $_POST['ogori']");
        if(isset($ogoriget) && $ogoriget !=''){
            if($ogoriget === '0'){
                $ogorihiritu = 0;
                return $ogorihiritu;
                detailCalc::ogoriPrice();

            }else if($ogoriget === '1'){
                $ogorihiritu = 1;
                return $ogorihiritu;
                detailCalc::ogoriPrice();

            }else if($ogoriget === '1.5'){
                $ogorihiritu = 1.5;
                return $ogorihiritu;
                detailCalc::ogoriPrice();

            }else if($ogoriget === '2'){
                $ogorihiritu = 2;
                return $ogorihiritu;
                detailCalc::ogoriPrice();

            }else{
                error_echo::ogori_error1();
            }
        }else{
            error_echo::ogori_error2();
        }

    }

    static function seasonReceive(){
        $seasonget = mysql_query("SELECT season FROM seriveuser where season = $_POST['season']");
        if(isset($seasonget) && $seasonget != ''){
            if($seasonget === '春' || $seasonget === '秋'){
                 finalCalc::plusCalc();
            }else if($seasonget ==='夏'　|| $seasonget === '冬'){
                addPrice::seasonPrice();        
            }else{
                error_echo::seasonReceive_error1();
            }

        }else{
            error_echo::seasonReceive_error2();
        }
    }

    static function accidentreceive(){

            $accidentget = mysql_query("SELECT jiko FROM serviceuser where jiko = $_POST['jiko']");

        if(isset($accidentget) && $accidentget != ''){
            if(is_numeric($accidentget) && 1<= strlen($accidentget) <= 2){
                addPrice::accident();
            }else{
                error_echo::accidentreceive_error1();
            }
        }else{
            error_echo::accidentreceive_error2();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Line 275 o fuserchoice_control.php  check around this line

Comment: line 275 wa doko desu ka?

Comment: static function commodityrecive () {
    //物価の情報を受け取る
   global $commodityget;
   global $sql10;

   $sql5 = sprintf("SELECT commodity FROM contrydata where destname = '%s'",
      mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['destination'])
     );
   $commodityget = mysqli_query($db,$sql5);


   
    
   if(isset($commodityget) && $commodityget != ''){
    if(is_numeric($commodityget)){
     addPrice::commoditycost();

    }else{
     error_echo::commodityrecieve_error1(); 
    }
   }else{
    error_echo::commodityrecieve_error2();
   }
    
  }

Comment: Provide function/few lines above commodityrecive() function.

Comment: static function choicemove(){ 

   
   if(isset($_POST['localmove']) && $_POST['localmove'] != ''){
    
    if($_POST['localmove'] === '自動車'){
     addPrice::localcarcost();
    }else if($_POST['localmove'] === '電車'){
     addPrice::localtraincost();
    }else if($_POST['localmove'] === 'タクシー'){
     addPrice::localtaxycost();
    }else if($_POST['localmove'] === 'バス'){
     addPrice::localbuscost();
    }else if($_POST['localmove'] === '高速鉄道(新幹線など)'){ 
     addPrice::localnewlinecost();
    }else{
     error_echo::choicemove_error2();
    }
    
   }else
error_echo::choicemove_error2();}
}

Comment: Brackets are not matching choicemove() function.

Comment: You have an extra closing brace in your `choicemove()` function http://jsfiddle.net/LWxq5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the previous function choicemove() you have 1 extra '}':

```
static function choicemove() { 
    if(isset($_POST['localmove']) && $_POST['localmove'] != '') {   
        if($_POST['localmove'] === '自動車'){ 
            addPrice::localcarcost(); 
        } else if($_POST['localmove'] === '電車') { 
            addPrice::localtraincost(); 
        } else if($_POST['localmove'] === 'タクシー'){ 
            addPrice::localtaxycost(); 
        } else if($_POST['localmove'] === 'バス'){ 
            addPrice::localbuscost(); 
        } else if($_POST['localmove'] === '高速鉄道(新幹線など)'){ 
            addPrice::localnewlinecost(); 
        } else{ 
            error_echo::choicemove_error2(); 
        } 
    } else 
        error_echo::choicemove_error2();
} }
```

Remove this last '}' and try your code again.

Comment: and he has to put that brace for the second function. I have posted the corrected syntax in my answer. But I think he haven't checked the entire code I pasted.

Comment: If this is the solution then please mark this as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't closed the brace for second function (qualityrecive)

```
        $sql5 = sprintf("SELECT commodity FROM contrydata where destname = '%s'",
                    mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['destination'])
                );
        $commodityget = mysqli_query($db,$sql5);




        if(isset($commodityget) && $commodityget != ''){
            if(is_numeric($commodityget)){
                addPrice::commoditycost();

            }else{
                error_echo::commodityrecieve_error1();  
            }
        }else{
            error_echo::commodityrecieve_error2();
        }

    }


    //クオリティ情報のレシーブ@コントローラ
    static function qualityrecive(){

        global $qualityget;
        $qualityget = mysqli_query("SELECT quality FROM serviceuser where destname = $_POST['quality']");
            if(isset($qualityget) && $qualityget != ''){    
                if($qualityget === '高級'){//一般&安い
                    return $qualityhigh;
                    addPrice::qualitycost();

                }else if($qualityget === '一般'){
                    return $qualotynomal;
                    addPrice::qualitycost();

                }else if($qalityget === '安い'){
                    return $qualitylow;
                    addPrice::qualitycost();

                }else{
                    error_echo::qualityreceive_error1();
                }
            }else{
                error_echo::qualityrecieve_error2();
            }

}


    //人数の情報をレシーブ
    static function ninnzuurecive(){


        $ninnzuuget = mysql_query("SELECT numberofpeople FROM serviceuser where destname = $_POST['ninnzuu']");
        if(isset($ninnzuuget) && $ninnzuuget != ''){
            if(is_numeric($ninnzuuget)){
                continue;
            }else{
                error_echo::ninnzuureceive_error1();
            }

            if(2 <= $ninnzuuget <= 9){  

                return $ninnzuuget;
                addPrice::ninnzuuprice();
                //$以下に注意して
            }else{
                error_echo::ninnzuureceive_error2();
            }

        }else{
            error_echo::ninnzuureceive_error3();
        }
    }       



    //プレゼントの有無とかを受信
    static function surprise(){
        $surpriseget = mysql_query("SELECT surprise FROM serviceuser where destname = $_POST['surprise']");
        if(isset($surpriseget) && $surpriseget != ''){
            //正常
            if($surpriseget === 'あり'){
                addPrice::buyPresent();
                addPrice::surpriseSetting();
            }else　if($surpriseget === 'なし'){
                //つまりはbirthdayクラスには行かないってこと
                finalCalc::plusCalc();

            }else{
                error_echo::surprise_error1();
            }

        }else{
            //異常
            error_echo::surprise_error2();

        }
    }




    static function ogori(){
        //どんくらい奢るのか計算


        $ogoriget = mysql_query("SELECT ogori FROM serviceuser where ogori = $_POST['ogori']");
        if(isset($ogoriget) && $ogoriget !=''){
            if($ogoriget === '0'){
                $ogorihiritu = 0;
                return $ogorihiritu;
                detailCalc::ogoriPrice();

            }else if($ogoriget === '1'){
                $ogorihiritu = 1;
                return $ogorihiritu;
                detailCalc::ogoriPrice();

            }else if($ogoriget === '1.5'){
                $ogorihiritu = 1.5;
                return $ogorihiritu;
                detailCalc::ogoriPrice();

            }else if($ogoriget === '2'){
                $ogorihiritu = 2;
                return $ogorihiritu;
                detailCalc::ogoriPrice();

            }else{
                error_echo::ogori_error1();
            }
        }else{
            error_echo::ogori_error2();
        }

    }

    static function seasonReceive(){
        $seasonget = mysql_query("SELECT season FROM seriveuser where season = $_POST['season']");
        if(isset($seasonget) && $seasonget != ''){
            if($seasonget === '春' || $seasonget === '秋'){
                 finalCalc::plusCalc();
            }else if($seasonget ==='夏'　|| $seasonget === '冬'){
                addPrice::seasonPrice();        
            }else{
                error_echo::seasonReceive_error1();
            }

        }else{
            error_echo::seasonReceive_error2();
        }
    }

    static function accidentreceive(){

            $accidentget = mysql_query("SELECT jiko FROM serviceuser where jiko = $_POST['jiko']");

        if(isset($accidentget) && $accidentget != ''){
            if(is_numeric($accidentget) && 1<= strlen($accidentget) <= 2){
                addPrice::accident();
            }else{
                error_echo::accidentreceive_error1();
            }
        }else{
            error_echo::accidentreceive_error2();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: DId you tried the code I have pasted here? Or just tried adding a brace at the end of second function??

Answer (score 1):

change to:

```
static function choicemove(){ 
    if(isset($_POST['localmove']) && $_POST['localmove'] != ''){
        if($_POST['localmove'] === '自動車'){ 
            addPrice::localcarcost(); 
        }else if($_POST['localmove'] === '電車'){
            addPrice::localtraincost(); 
        }else if($_POST['localmove'] === 'タクシー'){ 
            addPrice::localtaxycost(); 
        }else if($_POST['localmove'] === 'バス'){ 
            addPrice::localbuscost(); 
        }else if($_POST['localmove'] === '高速鉄道(新幹線など)'){ 
            addPrice::localnewlinecost(); 
        }else{ 
            error_echo::choicemove_error2(); 
        } 
    }else{
        error_echo::choicemove_error2();
    } 
}
```

Comment: That won't make a difference. It will still work http://codepad.viper-7.com/FjZ7AF